# program throwing error when called through subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

**Summary**

I am trying to call an external program through subprocess call commands.
My program runs fine when called directly from the terminal. However, when called through subprocess, the program throws an error.

**Details**

I am trying to call the program [Zimpl](http://zimpl.zib.de/) in Python. Zimpl is a program that reads a model file, as well as two input files and produces an output file.

When I call Zimpl through the command line here's the output:

```
****************************************************
* Zuse Institute Mathematical Programming Language *
* Release 3.3.2 Copyright (C)2012 by Thorsten Koch *
****************************************************
*   This is free software and you are welcome to   *
*     redistribute it under certain conditions     *
*      ZIMPL comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY     *
****************************************************

Reading model.zpl
Reading parfile.par
Reading values.txt
Instructions evaluated: 103351
Name: model.zpl   Variables: 156   Constraints: 546   Non Zeros: 2280
Writing [model.lp]
Writing [model.tbl]
```

When I call through the subprocess library with the command:

```
s = subprocess.check_call(['zimpl', 'model.zpl'])
print(s)
```

here is what I get instead:

```
****************************************************
* Zuse Institute Mathematical Programming Language *
* Release 3.3.2 Copyright (C)2012 by Thorsten Koch *
****************************************************
*   This is free software and you are welcome to   *
*     redistribute it under certain conditions     *
*      ZIMPL comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY     *
****************************************************

Reading model.zpl
Reading parfile.par
Reading values.txt
*** Error 800: File model.zpl Line 24 : Symbol "VALUE" not initialised

*** ximize obj :   sum <i,j> in Particles : (x[i,j] *  VALUE[i,j]);
***                                                     ^^^
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runscript.py", line 153, in <module>
    evaluateLevel(0, sublevels[0], values)
  File "./runscript.py", line 111, in evaluateLevel
    s = subprocess.check_call(['zimpl', 'model.zpl'])
  File "/Users/macbook/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['zimpl', 'model.zpl']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

In the Zimpl model file, the line that initiates VALUE is this:

```
param VALUE[Particles] := read "values.txt" as "<1n,2n> 3n";
```

In other words, VALUE is read from file. I even went to the source code of Zimpl to see when the error "Symbol .. not initialised" occurs. This is what I found:

```
case SYM_ERR : /* should not happen */
               sprintf(errmsg, "Symbol \"%s\" not initialised\n", yytext);
               yyerror(errmsg);
```

I don't know why this is happening. My guess is it might be related to buffers or executing the program too quickly that does not give Zimpl time to read the data.txt file.

It gets even more interesting.. If I call the Popen command and print the output instead, the program is run only partially.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["zimpl",
                    "model.zpl"],
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    universal_newlines=True,
                    bufsize=0)
proc.wait() # I tried with and without this line, same output

for line in proc.stdout:
    print(line),

****************************************************
* Zuse Institute Mathematical Programming Language *
* Release 3.3.2 Copyright (C)2012 by Thorsten Koch *
****************************************************
*   This is free software and you are welcome to   *
*     redistribute it under certain conditions     *
*      ZIMPL comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY     *
****************************************************

Reading model.zpl
Reading parfile.par
Reading values.txt
```

Although now it does not throw an error, no file is generated as it was supposed to be. Now.. if I don't attempt to print the stdout by removing the lines:

```
for line in proc.stdout:
    print(line),
```

Voila!! Although I don't see the output of the program, the files are generated. Why could this be happening? I didn't mention everything that I tried such as playing around with the parameters, trying different buffsizes, using other commands from the subprocess library etc.. Nothing else worked. And if I want to see the output of my program, I can't.

Finally, if I run the command:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["zimpl",
                    "model.zpl"],
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                 #   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    universal_newlines=True,
                    bufsize=0)
```

this produces the output AND the files correctly, but the program hangs and waits for an input:

```
****************************************************
* Zuse Institute Mathematical Programming Language *
* Release 3.3.2 Copyright (C)2012 by Thorsten Koch *
****************************************************
*   This is free software and you are welcome to   *
*     redistribute it under certain conditions     *
*      ZIMPL comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY     *
****************************************************

Reading model.zpl
Reading parfile.par
Reading values.txt
MacBook-Pro:model macbookpro$ Instructions evaluated: 103351
Name: model.zpl   Variables: 156   Constraints: 546   Non Zeros: 2280
Writing [model.lp]
Writing [model.tbl]
```

I would appreciate very much if someone could explain what's going on and suggests a way that produces the output and the files AND the program terminates normally, without waiting for an input.

Comment: Bit of a lazy solution here but have you tried using `subprocess.check_call("zimpl model.zpl", shell = True)`

Comment: Or `subprocess.check_output("zimple model.zpl", shell=True)`

Comment: yes, they both return the same VALUE not initialised error

Comment: This is out of my depth, sorry. Thought I'd take a stab

Comment: it's out of any depth, doesn't make any sense :D thanks anyway

Comment: Have you tried to add a timeout between the subprocess and the print? And what about the `communicate()` option?

Comment: For a timeout: `import time` and the line will be : `time.sleep(A)`. A = number of seconds you want to do a timeout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I tried them both but they didn't work for me. In the end, I gave up :)